# PHP database (sql) query in smarty tpl

Tags: php, sql, smarty

Im a "noob" in smarty. I need to execute following code in one of my .tpl files:

```
  <? // SELECT sql query
$sql = "SELECT 'id' , 'title' FROM `forum_posts` WHERE bid = '1' ORDER BY 'date' DESC LIMIT 4"; 

// perform the query and store the result
$result = query($sql);

// if the $result contains at least one row
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row from $result
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<tr>
        <td><a href="http://www.site.com/forum.php?topic='. $row['id']. '">'. $row['title']. '</a>  </td>  
        </tr>   ';
  }
}
else {
  echo 'No news';
}
?>
```

I've been trying for 3 hours now, surfing all over the web but without success. 
Help please!

Comment: Why are your templates executing queries?

Comment: You are approaching this incorrectly. Don't execute the query in your template file. Execute it in the PHP file which calls the template, then `$smarty->assign()` the rows fetched to an array which gets used in the template.

Comment: I have created a file news.php and included it into a tpl file with: `{include file='newsacc.php'} ` but I guess it's wrong. I have no "smarty" idea whatsoever. I have this script which uses smarty and just want to add this widget. 
Any good examples about what you are saying?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using quotes instead of backtick for column name, simply change them to avoid the error

```
SELECT `id` , `title` FROM `forum_posts` WHERE `bid` = '1' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 4";
```

Answer (score 0):

require('../libs/SmartySQL.class.php');

$smarty = new SmartySQL(  array('pdo_dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=db_name;host=localhost', 
            'pdo_username' => 'username', 
            'pdo_password' => 'password', 
            'pdo_driver_options' => array() ) );

$smarty->display('index.tpl');

Comment: You should not answer just by a piece of code. A bit of explanation are welcomed.